# store data in drupal 8

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I have created form using twig template, the form has first name,last name and email.I need to save those values to database.

how can I create new table and store data in it??

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="/action_page.php">
First name: <input type="text" name="FirstName"><br>
Last name: <input type="text" name="LastName"><br>
Email: <input type="text" name="email" value="Mouse"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone help on that please??

Comment: Way to broad to answer. You should do some tutorials on creating Drupal modules.

Comment: @2pha ok thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You should use drupal's form api to create the form. Your way is not really "drupalish" way. Then you can define custom content type, with all the fields you need and if form submission handler of your form you can create new nodes in that type with data your form collected.

So google a bit, check some tutorial on form api, and how to make custome form and also on custom content types in drupal. Not that scare as it maybe looks to you right now.

Or, check on webform module that comes with D8 default installation, maybe you can use it instead!

Comment: Hello MilanG thanks for your answer,U mean we cant submit form with twig template??

Comment: Hello MilanG thanks for your answer,U mean we cant submit above form in drupal??

Comment: Yes you can. You can put anything you like in twig template. Just it's not common way forms on drupal sites are made. If you pick to use some CMS (framework, what every) you should follow guidelines defined by creators of that CMS. Other way...why to bother at all using Drupal?

Comment: Sir actually,Im not a designer I got designed forms from designers they used html and css to design form, so I need to store the form data in DB ,thats what my problem is.

Comment: I have been told this has to be done in drupal 8 and Im new to drupal8

Comment: Well, one way is to store your data the way it's "normal" for drupal. The way I described. Then you can automatically administrate (edit) your content, you can use view module to make DB queries and so on. Other way would be creating it fully custom. In that case you will have all those functionalities available and they would have to be made also custom, which i don't recommend.